# How to do redirect from url to html file without downloading it in nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, url

I need to redirect url to html file located on the file system. This is that I have tried so far:

```
location /this/some/url {
    alias /path/to/the/file.html
}
```

When I run this the redirect works but the browser tries to download the html file. Instead I expect it to render the html page in the browser.

Comment: Please show your full nginx configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
location /this/some/url {
    index file.html;
    alias /path/to/the/;
}
```

Please read about alias: https://nginx.ru/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias

and about index file: https://nginx.ru/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html

And everything become clear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just one more question. How can append an empty request parameter to the `/this/some/url`? For instance, `/this/some/url?some_parameter=`?

Comment: You are welcome! Try this one:  try_files $uri /file.html?arg1=x&arg2=y

Comment: Should I put this line `try_files $uri /file.html?arg1=x&arg2=y` just after the index and alias lines?  Or instead of the index line. I tried various combinations but it doesn't work. It either returns 404 or shows the html page but without the appended parameter.